# renaming files base on the file structure

Tags: python-3.x

I have a directory structure containing folders and files:

dir/dir/dir/file1.jpg
dir/dir/dir/file2.jpg
dir/dir/dir/file3.jpg
dir/dir/dir/dir/file1.jpg
dir/dir/dir/dir/file2.jpg
dir/dir/dir/dir/file3.jpg

I would like to copy and rename each image based on the folder structure, so:

dir_dir_dir_file1.jpg
dir_dir_dir_file2.jpg
dir_dir_dir_file3.jpg

dir_dir_dir_dir_file1.jpg
dir_dir_dir_dir_file2.jpg
dir_dir_dir_dir_file3.jpg

So far I have this, but I could do with some help/pointers.

```
import os
import sys

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in 
    os.walk('/Users/Gerrit/Documents/gygaia/Python_scripts/Photos', topdown=True):
    # print path to all subdirectories first.
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, subdirname))

# print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        #print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
        path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)

    #replace path string '/' with '_'
    #replace path string '\' with '_'
    print(path.replace('/', '_'))
```

**edited**

```
import os, subprocess
from shutil import copyfile
os.chdir('C:\\Users\Gerrit\Documents\gygaia\Python_scripts\Photos')     
root_dir =  os.getcwd()
def file_mover():
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".jpg"):
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
            src = (os.path.join(root, file))
            # remove the cwd from the path
            path = src.replace(root_dir, "")
            # replace \\ with _ in the paths
            path = path.replace("\\", "_")
            file_name = path.replace("_", "",1)
            # copy and rename the jpg files including the file path
            os.chdir("..")
            dst = os.getcwd() + "\\Photos_mirror"
            copyfile(src, dst)
file_mover()
```

**Old EDIITED**
I've managed to get this far, but the copy file command is not working, its saying permissions error 12, I've tried opening python IDE with admin rights (windows) but it still wont work, here's the code:

```
###Script to copy images and rename them by their former directory location### 

import os, sys, subprocess, glob
from shutil import copyfile

def file_mover():

#First set working directory - we don't want to rename everything!
os.chdir('C:\\Users\Gerrit\Documents\gygaia\Python_scripts\Photos')     
path =  os.getcwd()
print (path)

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
# print path to all subdirectories first.
print("loop 1")
for subdirname in dirnames:
    print(os.path.join(dirname, subdirname))
    path2 = (os.path.join(dirname, subdirname))

    # remove the cwd from the path
    path = path2.replace(path, "")

    # replace \\ with _ in the paths
    path = path.replace("\\", "_")
    path = path.replace("_", "",1)
    path = path + ("_")
    print("loop 2")

    # copy and rename the jpg files including the file path
    os.chdir("..")
    dst = os.getcwd() + "\\Photos_mirror"
    src = dirname +("\\")

    copyfile(src, dst)
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I'm trying to rename files by their folder structure, but I'm not sure how best to proceed. Pointers/examples welcome

Comment: Try my edited code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** Try this:

```
import os
import shutil

wd = r'C:\Users\Gerrit\Documents\gygaia\Python_scripts\Photos'
def file_mover():
  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(wd):
    for file in files:
      if file.endswith(".jpg"):
        src = os.path.join(path, file)
        #Assuming 'Photos_mirror' folder is in folder which images are located
        dst = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Photos_mirror")
        if not os.path.exists(dst): #Checks 'Photos_mirror' folder exists otherwise creates
          os.makedirs(dst)
        new_name = src.replace(wd+'\\', '').replace('\\', '_')
        new_dst = os.path.join(dst, new_name)
        if not os.path.isfile(new_dst):
          shutil.copy(src, dst)
          old_dst = os.path.join(dst, file)
          #Assuming your /dir/dir/... structure is inside of your working directory (wd)
          os.rename(old_dst, new_dst)
        else:
          continue

file_mover()
```

If you have questions or I misunderstand your problem, feel free to comment

Comment: in src.replace do you mean wd? Although nothing is copied.

Comment: Did you copy paste my script and no result anyway? Check inside of your `wd` folder

Comment: I copy pasted your script, said wp not defined, I changed it to wd, it ran but no files appeared in my Photos_mirror dir. I've added some new code above which throws a permissions error.

Comment: Where is your `Photos_mirror` folder located?

Comment: Perfect, if it could have a 'if exists skip when copying' so the script can copy new files, that would be great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, added file existance check

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pathlib.Path` to simplify most of this

I could not test this, but something like this should work

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

start_path = Path(<start_dir>) 
dest_dir = Path(<dest_dir>)

for file in start_path.glob('**/*.jpg'):
    new_name = dest_dir.joinpath('_'.join(file.parts))
    print('renaming %s to %s' % (str(file), str(new_name)))
    # file.rename(new_name)  # move
    # shutil.copy(file, new_name) # copy, newer python
    # shutil.copy(str(file), str(new_name)) # copy, older python
```

Remove the correct # when the test succeeds